# Wrap multiline string (preserving existing linebreaks) in Python?

Tags: python, string, word-wrap

Consider this example:

```
import textwrap
import pprint

mystr=r"""
First line.
Second line.
The third line is a very long line, which I would like to somehow wrap; wrap at 80 characters - or less, or more! ... can it really be done ??"""

pprint.pprint(textwrap.wrap(mystr,80))
```

The string `mystr` is already a multiline string, given that it contains linebreaks; however, if I run this script, I get as output:

```
[' First line. Second line. The third line is a very long line, which I would like',
 'to somehow wrap; wrap at 80 characters - or less, or more! ... can it really be',
 'done ??']
```

... which means that `textwrap.wrap` first "joined" the multiline string (that is, removed the existing linebreaks in it), and only then wrapped it (i.e. split it at the given number of characters).

How can I wrap a multiline string, such that the line feeds are preserved? that is, in this case, the expected output would be:

```
['First line.', 
 'Second line.', 
 'The third line is a very long line, which I would like to somehow wrap; wrap at',
 '80 characters - or less, or more! ... can it really be done ??']
```

---

EDIT; thanks to comment by @u_mulder, I tried:

```
textwrap.wrap(mystr,80,replace_whitespace=False)
```

and with that I get:

```
['\nFirst line.\nSecond line.\nThe third line is a very long line, which I would like',
 'to somehow wrap; wrap at 80 characters - or less, or more! ... can it really be',
 'done ??']
```

The line breaks seem to be preserved, but as "inline" characters; so here the first element is a multiline string in itself -- and so it is not as I require it, with every line as an array element.

Comment: Some similar case, maybe it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902521/python-textwrap-wrap-causing-issue-with-n

Comment: Thanks @u_mulder - turns out, this is not a duplicate; please see edit in the OP

Comment: Just a side note, the reason the behaviors are not as you expect are that (according to the docs) `pprint - Support to pretty-print lists, tuples, & dictionaries recursively` (not strings). And `help(textwrap.wrap)` gives ` Wrap a single paragraph of text, returning a list of wrapped lines.` So we see it expects a single paragraph in the input string, not several paragraphs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the newlines back after splitting:

```
import textwrap
import pprint
import itertools

mystr=r"""
First line.
Second line.
The third line is a very long line, which I would like to somehow wrap; wrap at 80 characters - or less, or more! ... can it really be done ??"""

wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width = 80)
mylist = [wrapper.wrap(i) for i in mystr.split('\n') if i != '']
mylist = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist))

pprint.pprint(mylist)
```

Output:

```
['First line.',
 'Second line.',
 'The third line is a very long line, which I would like to somehow wrap; wrap at',
 '80 characters - or less, or more! ... can it really be done ??']
```

Comment: Thanks, @MalikBrahimi - but I don't see how this wraps at say 80 characters? Did you try this at all?

Comment: No, I'll have that working in few minutes, give me a little time.

Comment: Many thanks @MalikBrahimi - that works, but the output is exactly the same as in the edit I just made in the OP; that is, if you do `pprint.pprint(mylist)`, you'll see that the first item in the array is a multiline string in itself, it's not one line per element as I wanted it to; any ideas about that?

Comment: What exactly do you need as I probably don't understand? Do you want the list now as a string?

Comment: @sdaau - `pprint.pprint(mystr)` (without wrapping) shows '`\nFirst line.\nSecond line.\nThe third ...'`. I think you're falling victim to an expected behavior of `pprint`.

Comment: @sdaau Forget about pretty print. Print the list as is, and you'll see the answer.

Comment: Thanks @MalikBrahimi, @mtrw- I want to get the output that I wrote in the OP under "that is, in this case, the expected output would be... " - each line, regardless if it was originally a line or split afterwards, should be a its own item in the array; there should _not_ be an item in the array containing multiple lines, even if they are delimited by `\n` - in that case, there should be _separate_ array entries for each of those lines.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi - managed to do what I want; posted an answer below, but it's not as elegant as I'd want it to ... cheers!

Comment: @MalikBrahimi - if you insist on an accept, you should at least be bothered to a) post a fully compilable example, b) post the output - at least if the original poster did so. I edited your answer, and in that form I can accept it (even if I had to answer my question first, in order to edit your question, so I can accept it). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I found how to do what I want, but its kind of unelegant:

```
import textwrap
import pprint

mystr=r"""
First line.
Second line.
The third line is a very long line, which I would like to somehow wrap; wrap at 80 characters - or less, or more! ... can it really be done ??"""

#pprint.pprint(textwrap.wrap(mystr,80,replace_whitespace=False))

aa=[]
for ix in mystr.splitlines():
  if ix:
    if len(ix)<=80: aa.append(ix)
    else: aa.extend(textwrap.wrap(ix,80))

pprint.pprint(aa)
```

This results with:

```
['First line.',
 'Second line.',
 'The third line is a very long line, which I would like to somehow wrap; wrap at',
 '80 characters - or less, or more! ... can it really be done ??']
```

So:

- 1st elem: 'First line.' which was originally defined
- 2nd elem: 'Second line.' which was also originally defined
- 3rd elem: original third line was too long, so it is wrapped at 80 characters, first part of it is the 3rd element in the array
- 4th elem: contains the second part of the wrap of the original third line

That is what I wanted to achieve; note that this is a very different situation than when the first element in the array contains multiple lines, as in `['\nFirst line.\nSecond line.\nThe third line ...`.

Comment: Your solution is quite nice. You can simplify the code a bit by removing the `ifs`. Just: `for ix in mystr.splitlines(): aa += textwrap.wrap(ix,80)` gives the same result.