# regaining original line breaks pandas \n

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, text, replace, line-breaks

**Background**

I have the following sample df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['\n[STUFF]\nBut the here is \n\nBase ID : 00000 Date is Here \nfollow\n', 
                                   '\n[OTHER]\n\n\nFound Tom Dub \nhere\n  BATH # : E12-34567 MR # 000', 
                                   '\n[ANY]\nJane Ja So so \nBase ID : 11111 Date\n\n\n hey the \n\n  \n    \n\n\n'],
                    'Alt_Text' : ['[STUFF]But the here is Base ID : *A* Date is Here follow', 
                                   '[OTHER]Found *B* *B* here BATH # : *A* MR # *C*', 
                                   '[ANY]*B* *B*So so Base ID : *A* Date hey the '],


                      'ID': [1,2,3]

                     })
```

**Goal**

1) Create a new column `New_Text` that 2) regains the original linebreaks `\n` present in the `Text` column but contains the contents from the `Alt_Text` column

**Example**

`Text` Column, Row `0`:

```
\n[STUFF]\nBut the here is \n\nBase ID : 00000 Date is Here \nfollow\n
```

`Alt_Text` Column, Row `0`:

```
[STUFF]But the here is Base ID : *A* Date is Here follow
```

**Would like**

```
\n[STUFF]\nBut the here is \n\nBase ID : *A*  Date is Here \nfollow\n
```

**Desired Output**

```
   Text Alt_Text ID New_Text 
0                   \n[STUFF]\nBut the here is \n\nBase ID :  *A*  Date is Here \nfollow\n  
1                   \n[OTHER]\n\n\nFound *B* *B*  \nhere\n BATH # : *A*  MR # *C*   
2                   \n[ANY]\nJ*B* *B* So so \nBase ID : *A*  Date\n\n\n hey the \n\n \n \n\n\n
```

**Tried**

I have looked around SO including [Wrap multiline string (preserving existing linebreaks) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863889/wrap-multiline-string-preserving-existing-linebreaks-in-python) and  [Read Excel data using Pandas and retaining the line break of a cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55341061/read-excel-data-using-pandas-and-retaining-the-line-break-of-a-cell-value) amongst many others and none seem to be what I am looking to do.

**Question**

How do I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We [regex split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) `Text` and `Alt_Text` using capturing parentheses in the pattern:

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all
>   groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

Then we `zip` both lists taking separators containing line breaks from `Text` and anything else from `Alt_Text` and `join` the resulting list into `New_Text`:

```
def insert_line_breaks(text, alt_text):
    regex = re.compile(r'([^ \n\[\]]+)')
    text = regex.split(text)
    alt_text = regex.split(alt_text)
    return ''.join([t if '\n' in t else a for t,a in zip(text,alt_text)])

df['New_Text'] = df.apply(lambda r: insert_line_breaks(r.Text, r.Alt_Text), axis=1)
```

I guess there should be a space between the second `*B*` and `So` in the last row of `Alt_Text` and the `J` before the first `*B*` in the desired output is just a typo. In this case we get:

```
>>> df.New_Text
0            \n[STUFF]\nBut the here is \n\nCase ID : *A* Date is Here \nfollow\n
1                    \n[OTHER]\n\n\nFound *B* *B* \nhere\n  BATH # : *A* MR # *C*
2    \n[ANY]\n*B* *B* So so \nCase ID : *A* Date\n\n\n hey the \n\n  \n    \n\n\n
```